# How to differentiate between paid and free version of app in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, multiple-versions

Is there a way to enable certain features in the code base based on the version of the app that is running?  This is for a Xamarin Forms cross platform app.  I plan to have a free, paid and enterprise version of apps.

Comment: No offense, but if you cannot figure out this on your owm, then perhaps you should start by making something smaller first?

Comment: No offense taken David.  I have developed apps in Android as well as in Windows.  Am aware of how to do it in those environments.  In fact, Windows Store provides a very easy way to do it.  Looking to see if there is an inbuilt provision in Xamarin Forms.  I know I can code it but I would rather not...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to handle this via your web services ie save when a user paid something in the cloud and check on your server if the user have permission to use a feature a then show it into the app of if you're planning to use in app purchases you can always create a dependency service to ask OS Stores if current user paid for a service, product via InApp purchases